# Exceptions during removing data from dynamic array

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dynamic-arrays

I don't have anyone here to ask here so I hope someone here will know what's going on.

I work on a adress book project. The main assumption is using dynamic array to store records and using text file as simply database.
There is class `Record` which consist of data such as name, surname, street, house number etc. Records are stored in dynamic array in class `AdressBook`. The application should have functions such as showing, adding, searching, deleting end editing records. When program starts the data from .txt file are loaded to array and when program ends then it saves all objects from array to text file. This is my AdressBook class:

```
class AdressBook
{
    int tableCap_;
    Record *recordTable_;
    int recordNum_;
public:
    AdressBook();
    int getTableCap();
    bool addRecord(const Record& newRecord);
    Record getRecord(int);
    void deleteRecord();
    void searchRecord();
    bool readFromFile();
    bool saveToFile();
}
```

I made show, add and search functions but i have problem with working with array after deleting records. Records are deleting correctly by this method:

```
void AdressBook::deleteRecord()
{
    // some code where i search record to delete
            Record *tempTable = new Record[tableCap_ - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                tempTable[j] = recordTable_[j];
            for (int j = i; j < tableCap_ - 1; j++)
                tempTable[j] = recordTable_[j+1];
            delete[] recordTable_;
            recordTable_ = tempTable;
            recordNum_--;
}
```

As I said. Deleting records works well. Problem appears when I want to do some action on array again. For example `saveToFile` function:

```
bool AdressBook::saveToFile()
{
    ofstream ofs("save.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
    for (int i = 0; i < getTableCap(); ++i)
    {
        ofs << recordTable_[i].name << endl;
        ofs << recordTable_[i].surname << endl;
        ofs << recordTable_[i].street << endl;
        ofs << recordTable_[i].houseNumber << endl;
        ofs << recordTable_[i].postalCode << endl;
        ofs << recordTable_[i].city << endl;
    }
    return 1;
    }
}
```

Record class:

```
class Record
{
public:
    string name, surname, street, houseNumber, postalCode, city;
    int classNumber;

    Record(string, string, string, string, string, string);
    Record();
    ~Record();

    friend istream& operator>>(fstream&, Record& t);
};
```

These function are called in `main.cpp` on object `PhoneBook phoneBook`.
Visual studio throw an exception *Access violation reading location*. I have no idea what can i change to avoid throwing these exceptions. Exceptions are thrown after deleting a record - everything works perfectly until deleting record.

Comment: Why not use vector?

Comment: What you can "change to avoid throwing these exceptions" is to find whatever bug in your program that results in memory corruption, and fix it. You have a bug somewhere in your code that results in undefined behavior, and corruption, which manifests itself at that point in the code. Just because a program crashes at one particular point doesn't mean that's where the bug is. The bug can be anywhere in your code, and you will need to figure it out, and fix it.

Comment: What's the difference between `recordNum_` and `tableCap_`?

Comment: Please post `Record`.  This function `getRecord(int);` returns a Record by value.  If you call that function anywhere, and `Record` does not have correct copy semantics, this can cause memory corruption.

Comment: I unfortunately can't use vector...
`recordNum_ ` starts from 1 and `tableCap_` starts from 0. I use it in other functions.

Comment: @syzmon9 -- ok, `Record` has correct copy semantics due to all members having correct copy semantics.  However -- *I have no idea what can i change to avoid throwing these exceptions.* -- in the comments, you were told `std::vector`.  That **is** how to avoid the exceptions.  Your code is still probably breakable if an `AddressBook` is copied or assigned, even with the answer you accepted.  The way to clear up those issues is to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `saveToFile` function, you are trying to print `tableCap` number of records:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getTableCap(); ++i)
```

But you only allocated `tableCap - 1` number of records in your `deleteRecord` function:

```
Record *tempTable = new Record[tableCap_ - 1];
```

Therefore you are going outside the bounds of the array causing the access violation.

Comment: That may not be the only problem.  See my comment above.

Comment: This is a clue! I forget to change `tableCap_` value. Instead of `tableCap - 1` i added line `tableCap_-=1;` and used `tableCap_` value in memory allocation. Thanks for help! I wouldn't come up with solution :)